# extjs tooltip issue

Tags: extjs

I really like the anchor and mousetrackign and the basic tooltps
http://www.extjs.com/examples/explorer.html#tooltips

How can I go about adding the extjs tooltip /data-qtip on the renderer code below?

```
var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: mystore,
        multiSelect: true,
        viewConfig: {
            emptyText: 'No images to display'
        },
        //reserveScrollOffset: true,
    renderTo: containerEl,

        columns: [
{
            text: 'Class',
            flex: 10,
            dataIndex: 'ClassName',
            renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
   return Ext.String.format('<a href="#" class="tooltip2">{0}<span>{0}</span></a>', value);
        }

   ]     
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Ext.QuickTips.init();` after `Ext.onReady()` call and in your renderer add:

```
metaData.attr = 'ext:qtip="your tooltip here"';
```

Comment: Where should  the Ext.onReady() go? for the renderrer  si something like this --> renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
   return Ext.String.format('<a href="#" class="tooltip2">{0}<span>{0}</span></a>', value);
        }

Comment: You just have to call the QuickTips.init() before you use it. The renderer is used to change what and how your data is displayed. You can just return value to have it show in the list. The metaData parameter is used for adding a class or id (metaData.css) or an atribute, in this case the ext:qtip, shich will allow for a mouseover tooltip popup. You can add the value parameter to the tooltip as well, just break the string up and place value there.

Comment: I realize I was a little vague in my statement about returning value. Your current return statement is fine.